# Custom File Format

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am new to Custom File Formats. I am trying to execute a WordCount program via
 MapReduce. I am using the following classes
**WordKey.class** (takes words as the keys)
**MyInputFormat.class**
**MyRecordReader.class**
**MyOutputFormat.class**
**MyRecordWriter.class**
**MyMapper.class**
**MyReducer.class**
I have implemented the mapper in a way as shown below
`public class MyMapper extends Mapper<WordKey,WordValue,Text,IntWritable>{//rest of the business logic }`

---

**My question is**: 
Can the inputKeys and the input Values to the mapper be customised like the way I wrote in the code given above; Or something else could be the solution for the same?

PLEASE SUGGEST
Thanks in Advance :)

---

**The Following are the Mapper and The Reducer Codes**

```
**Mapper**




  public class MyMapper extends Mapper<StudentKey, PassValue,PassValue,IntWritable> {
        public void map(StudentKey key,PassValue value,Context context)throws IOException,InterruptedException
        {


                context.write(new PassValue(value.getResStatus()),new IntWritable(1));

        }
    }
```

---

**Here is the Code for the reduce method**

```
 public class MyReducer extends
        Reducer<PassValue, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {
int sum=0;
public void reduce(PassValue key,Iterable<IntWritable>value,Context context)throws IOException,InterruptedException{
    for(IntWritable x:value)
    {
        sum+=x.get();
    }
    context.write(new Text(key.toString()), new IntWritable(sum));
}
}
```

**Code For the RecordReader**

```
public class MyRecordReader extends RecordReader<StudentKey, PassValue> {
    private StudentKey key;
    private PassValue value;
    private LineRecordReader reader=new LineRecordReader();
    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
        reader.close();
    }

    @Override
    public StudentKey getCurrentKey() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        return key;
    }

    @Override
    public PassValue getCurrentValue() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        // return the value
        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public float getProgress() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        return reader.getProgress();
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(InputSplit is, TaskAttemptContext tac)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        reader.initialize(is, tac);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean nextKeyValue() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        boolean nextKeyValueStatus=reader.nextKeyValue();
        if(nextKeyValueStatus)
        {
            if(key==null)
            {
                key=new StudentKey();
            }if(value==null)
            {
                value=new PassValue();
            }
            Text line=reader.getCurrentValue();
            String tokens[]=line.toString().split(",");
            key.setName(new Text(tokens[0]));
            key.setRoll(tokens[1]); //string is acceptable here because the setRoll has been customised apart from the normal 
                                    // framework structure
            value.setResStatus(tokens[2]);
        }
        return nextKeyValueStatus;
    }

}
```

**Code For the RecordWriter**

```
public class MyRecordWriter extends RecordWriter<PassValue, IntWritable> {
    private DataOutputStream out;
    public MyRecordWriter(DataOutputStream out)
    {
        super();
        this.out=out;
    }
    public MyRecordWriter(FSDataOutputStream fileOut) {
        this.out=fileOut;
    }
    @Override
    public void close(TaskAttemptContext tac) throws IOException,
            InterruptedException {
        out.close();

    }
List<IntWritable> x=new ArrayList<IntWritable>();
    @Override
    public void write(PassValue arg0, IntWritable arg1) throws IOException,
            InterruptedException {
        x.add(arg1);
        //write key First
        out.writeBytes(arg0.toString());
        for(IntWritable y:x)
        {
            out.writeBytes(",");
            out.writeBytes(String.valueOf(y.get()));
        }
        out.writeBytes("\r\n");
    }

}
```

**Code For the OutputFormat**

```
  public class MyOutputFormat extends FileOutputFormat<PassValue,IntWritable> {

        @Override
        public RecordWriter<PassValue, IntWritable> getRecordWriter(
                TaskAttemptContext tac) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Path currPath=FileOutputFormat.getOutputPath(tac);
            Path fullPath=new Path(currPath,"result.txt");

            FileSystem fs=currPath.getFileSystem(tac.getConfiguration());
            FSDataOutputStream fileOut=fs.create(fullPath, tac);
            return new MyRecordWriter(fileOut);
        }

    }
```

**Code For Custom Key**

```
public class StudentKey implements WritableComparable<StudentKey> {
    private Text name;
    private IntWritable roll;
    public StudentKey()
    {

    }

public StudentKey(Text name, IntWritable roll) {
    super();
    this.name = name;
    this.roll = roll;
}
public StudentKey(Text name)
{
    super();
    this.name=name;
}


/**
 * @return the name
 */
public Text getName() {
    return name;
}

/**
 * @param name the name to set
 */
public void setName(Text name) {
    this.name = name;
}

/**
 * @return the roll
 */
public IntWritable getRoll() {
    return roll;
}

/**
 * @param roll the roll to set
 */
public void setRoll(IntWritable roll) {
    this.roll = roll;
}
public void setRoll(String roll) {
    this.roll = new IntWritable(Integer.parseInt(roll));
}

@Override
public void readFields(DataInput arg0) throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    this.name.readFields(arg0);
    this.roll.readFields(arg0);
}

@Override
public void write(DataOutput arg0) throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    this.name.write(arg0);
    this.roll.write(arg0);  }

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see java.lang.Object#hashCode()
 */
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + ((name == null) ? 0 : name.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((roll == null) ? 0 : roll.hashCode());
    return result;
}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see java.lang.Object#equals(java.lang.Object)
 */
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    StudentKey other = (StudentKey) obj;
    if (name == null) {
        if (other.name != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!name.equals(other.name))
        return false;
    if (roll == null) {
        if (other.roll != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!roll.equals(other.roll))
        return false;
    return true;
}

@Override
public int compareTo(StudentKey arg0) {
    int comp=this.name.compareTo(arg0.name);
    if(comp!=0)
    {
        return comp;
    }
    else return this.roll.compareTo(arg0.roll);
}

}
```

**Custom Value Class**

```
public class PassValue implements Writable {
    private Text resStatus;
    public PassValue()
    {
        resStatus=new Text();
    }
    public PassValue(Text resStatus)
    {
        super();
        this.resStatus=resStatus;
    }
    public PassValue(PassValue status)
    {
        super();
        this.resStatus=status.resStatus;
    }
    /**
     * @return the resStatus
     */
    public Text getResStatus() {
        return resStatus;
    }
    /**
     * @param resStatus the resStatus to set
     */
    public void setResStatus(Text resStatus) {
        this.resStatus = resStatus;
    }
    //String implementation
    public void setResStatus(String resStatus) {
        this.resStatus = new Text(resStatus);
    }
    @Override
    public void readFields(DataInput arg0) throws IOException {
        this.resStatus.readFields(arg0);
    }

    @Override
    public void write(DataOutput arg0) throws IOException {
        this.resStatus.write(arg0);
    }
    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see java.lang.Object#hashCode()
     */
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result
                + ((resStatus == null) ? 0 : resStatus.hashCode());
        return result;
    }
    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see java.lang.Object#equals(java.lang.Object)
     */
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        PassValue other = (PassValue) obj;
        if (resStatus == null) {
            if (other.resStatus != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!resStatus.equals(other.resStatus))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

}
```

**Driver Code**

```
public class DriverCode extends Configured implements Tool {
    static Configuration cf;
    @Override
    public int run(String[] arg0) throws IOException,InterruptedException,ClassNotFoundException {
        cf=new Configuration();
        Job j=Job.getInstance(cf);
        j.setJarByClass(DriverCode.class);
        j.setMapperClass(MyMapper.class);
        j.setMapOutputKeyClass(PassValue.class);
        j.setMapOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
//      j.setCombinerClass(WCReduce.class);
        j.setReducerClass(MyReducer.class);
        j.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        j.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);
        j.setInputFormatClass(MyInputFormat.class);
        j.setOutputFormatClass(MyOutputFormat.class);
        Path op=new Path(arg0[1]);
        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(j, new Path(arg0[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(j, op);
        op.getFileSystem(cf).delete(op, true);

        return j.waitForCompletion(true)?0:1;
    }

        public static void main(String args[])throws Exception{
            int res=ToolRunner.run(cf, new DriverCode(), args);
            System.exit(res);
        }
}
```

Comment: Can you please add what is your requirement when you thought of wordkey and wordvalue. That will help us to guide you better.

Comment: Actually I am practicing the concepts of Custom file format and I am using a text file which has the content in a single line, no new line characters. It might be an easy task to count the number of word occurrences by using the vendor defined Box classes yet I find it interesting to customize it because I am getting a problem with the delimiter in the RecordReader section. Hope I am pretty clear with my requirement. Thanks a lot for asking :)

Comment: Good. When you plan for your own input format, I assume you are aware of managing your own split and record reader. Happy coding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible but you have to write your own custom inputformat and recordreader class. The best approach would be to allow your mapper to read key as offset and value as your line and then use custom writable class for your mapper output key and value with your transformations.

Comment: Yes Vignesh,  I am in an agreement with your answer and I want you to know that I have tried to customise each and everything in the MR code whichever I could.

Comment: The code runs fine till the mapper yet I have been facing problems with the reducer whenever I use the custom key as the output key class of the reducer.

Comment: I simply get a NullPointerException

Comment: If you get the mapper output correctly, then the nullpointer exception seems to be something wrong with the code. post your reducer code and mapper output and expected reducer output.

Comment: Till now I am not worried about the format of output rather I just want my program to run. I am posting the codes rightaway

Comment: **Mapper Code**
      public class MyMapper extends      Mapper<**StudentKey**,**PassValue**,**PassValue**,IntWritable>
    {  
        context.write(new PassValue(value.getResStatus()),new IntWritable(1));
    }
   }

**The above code is the mapper code that passes on a student result value(pass/fail) and I want the number of students who have passed and the number students who have failed**

Comment: I am sorry, being new to StackOverflow, I am not able to format the code correctly

Comment: Edit your question with your code. There you will be able to format the code.

Comment: The Codes have been embedded. Please go through them at you convinience and suggest me the places in the code wher I might have mistaken!
Thankyou :)

Comment: The code looks good. The reason for nullpointerexception could be studentkey is not passed from the mapper side, so when you try to get that in the reducer side it could be causing an issue. Try debugging in eclipse in local mode that would give you a better idea of where exactly the issue is.

Comment: Thank You @Vignesh; I got the isssue resolved, there was a problem with the RecordWriter